# Mongo Db search by indexed field

Tags: mongodb, search, full-text-search

I add field 'search_string' to my document and index it. `db.my_collection.createIndex({search_string: "text"})`
Search_string contains this: 'a ar are aren arena'.

I can find record with this: `db.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: 'ar'}})`, `db.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: 'аren'}})`, `db.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: 'arenа'}})`, but `db.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: 'а'}})` and `db.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: 'аre'}})` returns nothing. Why does it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MongoDB [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

> Match Operation
>
> Stop Words
>
> The $text operator ignores language-specific stop words, such as the and and in English.

Both "a" and "are" are in the list of default English language stopwords so will be ignored. A quick google search for English language stopwords will find plenty of pages with the full list.

Comment: How can I ignore this words?

Comment: From the manual again

"Search a Different Language

Use the optional $language field in the $text expression to specify a language that determines the list of stop words and the rules for the stemmer and tokenizer for the search string.

If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming."

So I guess specifying $language as none might do it.

Comment: $language: "none" - doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

By default, MongoDB uses English for text index and the stop words are not indexed.

> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.

So you should create your index like this :

`db.my_collection.createIndex(
   { search_string : "text" },
   { default_language: "none" }
)`

MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages).